# Qt is remembering previous versions of my code

Tags: c++, qt

What am I doing wrong?
1. I write some code in Qt Creator, it works.
2. I save all, copy the folder with all the files in it to another location for safekeeping.
3. Then I write more code. This additional code doesn't work and I've gone too far to undo it.
4. So I close Qt, delete that folder, move the earlier one back to where it was originally, and load the older version.

But Qt still gives me the same errors that the newer code gave me, and won't run. It seems to remember this newer (bad) code even though it no longer appears anywhere in Qt - and the problem persists over computer reboot. I feel I'm missing something very obvious, but Mr Google can't help at all.

Comment: Try rightclicking on your project -> clean and then try again. You should also get used to [git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) which has integration with Qt Creator instead of copying folders.

Comment: Running qmake might also be necessary. And if you did build in the source directory, you must clean it (`make clean distclean`) before switching to shadow builds (which are default with Qt Creator, and generally a good idea).

Comment: Ouch please learn to use a proper version control system... GIT, Mercurial, whatever, anything is better than the old "copy the folder around" ballet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Build->Rebuild all`. Your IDE is probably caching some of the previous results for performance reasons. I had the problem once using Qt Creator, and it solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks. The Build->Rebuild all did the trick. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the build folder. All that the build system knows about is the built files being newer than your now even older sources*. So a build won't succeed since plenty of intermediate files are wrong.

By the way, you really should be using version control, not moving folder around. I suggest git via smartgit, but that's just my personal preference. It's effortless.

* A build system could remember the absolute timestamps of the source used in the build and rebuild if they change, not only if the sources are newer than the results.